# Ошибка подключения

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проектом. Имеется проект и база данных .SQL
Как правильно присоединить её для работы? Я нашла строку для подключения (если это то). База данных .SQL рядом лежит с .exe

```
private User CurrentUser; // Текущий пользователь
private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; // Строка для подключения
```

Как её изменить? Чтобы можно было использовать т.е. подключится?

Проект по ссылке: https://dropmefiles.com/3qAs0
Помогите кто нибудь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тип называется App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PK306NEW-1;Initial Catalog=ИС1811_СистемаТестирования;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Проект Windows Forms (WinForms) для Windows 10.
Прикладное приложение (.exe).

P.S. Что нужно исправить в конфиге?

Comment: Без разницы где ваш проект, у вас sql server установлен?

Comment: @tym32167, да, установлен sql server 2012. не понимаю как запустить, чтобы заработало. можете посмотреть проект? очень нужно..

Comment: @tym32167, зайдите, пожалуйста в telegram. я оставила вам сообщение.

Comment: Повторю теперь в этой теме: покажите строку соединения! Она находится в файле конфигурации под названием "DefaultConnection". Конфиг называется app.config или web.config (я не знаю тип вашего приложения, вы почему-то не пишете всю необходимую информацию).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, отредактировала вопрос. конфиг - app.config. База данных .sql находиться в папке с .exe . как произвести подключение? в visual studio

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, sql server 2012 установлен

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, ответьте, пожалуйста. я не знаю какую ещё информацию Вам предоставить.. что нужно отредактировать в app.config? Data Source=PK306NEW-1 - это имя пользователя. Catalog=ИС1811_СистемаТестирования - папка где хранится программа и бд.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, строка соединения  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=PK306NEW-1;Initial Catalog=ИС1811_СистемаТестирования;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: Вот, теперь можно разбираться. У вас на компьютере установлен Sql Server с именем `PK306NEW-1`? У вас в этом сервере есть база данных с именем `ИС1811_СистемаТестирования`? Судя по ошибке, нет. Выясняйте, какой именно SqlServer у вас и впишите его имя.

Comment: `.sql` - это не база данных. Скорее всего, это текстовый файл, содержащий код sql. Возможно, это скрипт создания БД.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov,  на компьютере установлен Sql Server 2012 с именем USER-VIC. Да, базы данных с именем ИС1811_СистемаТестирования нету. Преобразовала её из  .sql в ИС1811_СистемаТестирования.mdf. Подключила её в SQL Server 2012 (обозреватель объектов). Вписала в app.config USER-VIC. А дальше что??

Comment: А как преобразовывали? Просто переименовали? Это неправильный способ. Правильный - создать базу при помощи SSMS, выполнить скрипт, указать имя базы в конфиге (примерно как вы поменяли имя сервера)

Comment: @A K, я открыла SQL Server дальше открыла .sql-файл и нажала F5 (преобразовать). Всё. Дальше указала в App.config имя и запустила программу всё заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо Вам большое

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы напишите ответ с описанием своих действий. И потом примите его.