# Ошибка подключения. База данных

Tags: c#, sql-server

Установлен SQL Server на Windows. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проектом. Имеется проект и база данных .SQL Как правильно присоединить её для работы? Я нашла строку для подключения (если это то). База данных .SQL рядом лежит с .exe

```
private User CurrentUser; // Текущий пользователь
private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString; // Строка для подключения
```

Как её изменить? Чтобы можно было использовать т.е. подключится?

Проект по ссылке: https://dropmefiles.com/3qAs0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в чем [отличие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1287449/220553)? Не надо дублировать свои вопросы!! Если есть что добавить, жмите "править", но не делайте новый.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, эхх, лучше посмотрели мой проект..

Comment: Это сайт не для того, чтобы смотреть чтьи-то проекты, это сайт для вопросов, которые будут иметь ценность для других посетителей. Завтра файл по вашей ссылке протухнет - вопрос для других бесполезен.